# Ping Adress IPV6

Tags: networking, ipv6, ping

Please, how to ping between the two machines (have IPV6 addresses)?

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `'man ping` should give you the information you want.  You could ping from the first machine to the second as either `ping 169.254.24.2` or `ping6 fe80::54c7:ef39:a57a:1802%10`

Comment: That looks strongly like Windows.

Comment: It is MS Windows shell command output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Link Local Addresses*

If your network doesn't have any infrastructure wich gives out IP addresses or handles it manual with static addresses, there are a way of still communicate between computers, and that is to use ***link local addresses***. A bit simplified, it is a randomized address that isn't allowed to pass routers, at all.  IPv4 private addresses can be routed through routers. They can pass hubs and switches though.

Your machine has no global address at all, but one IPv4 link local address and one IPv6 link local address.

**IPv4 Link Local Addresses**

If the two computers you want to communicate between are using IPv4 link local addresses, you can use them to communicate between them for example with `ping(8)`. The link local address range is `169.254.0.0/16`; see [rfc3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927).  Notice that link local addresses have nothing to do with global addresses or private addresses in IPv4.  Private addresses are some of these nets `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12`, `192.168.0.0/16`; see [rfc1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).

So if the computers have IPv4 addresses which are prefixed with `196.254` and are located on the same link, they can use those to communicat between them, with `ping(8)` or any other tool if you like.  Notice that the address usually are the same, but can change between reboots and networks.

**IPv6 Link Local Addresses**

If the two computers are located on the same link and uses IPv6, you can use their link local adresses. All devices that support IPv6 **must** have a link local addresses.  The address ranges of IPv6 are found in [rfc4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) and is in net `fe80::/64`.

So any IPv6 address with the prefix `fe80::` are a link local address and are uniq to the link.  So you can use those addresses to reach other computers on the same link, **but** you *must* add the interface you uses as a suffix to the address (or tell the application which interface to use.) That suffix starts with a `%` character followed by the interface id.

> ping6 ffe8::54c7:ef39:a57a:1802%11

Notice the `%11` in the end of the address.

Global IPv6 addresses usually is in the net `2000::/3`, starts with a `2` or `3`, but are always (nearly) divided in '/64'-net on lan. But look up the rfc:s to learn more about this.

Answer (score 6):

try *ping6*

```
man 8 ping6
```

you are running a class B subnet and both machines appear to be on the same subnet.  From your first machine:

```
ping6 fe80::54c7:ef39:a57a:1802
```

Comment: You need to add the device when you uses link local addresses, like this one.  They have the prefix `fe80::/10` (and often starts with that string).
IPv6 doesn't have any B class net, the IPv4 has.  But this address is a link local IPv4 address.  Read my answer for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know ping6 was a command. (I was trying to ping "ipv6.google.com", works now)